# Atom editor cannot open .tex file

Tags: latex, atom-editor, file-extension, tex

If I launch Atom first and then try to open a ".tex" file there is no issue, I am able to build and view a pdf of the Latex file. However, making Atom the default app to open ".tex" files, does not work (i.e. launching Atom by double clicking the Latex file). Same problem occured with ".latex" and ".ltx" file extensions.

Comment: I am using windows and the .tex file is not empty (contains latex). Actually I had set it to open with Atom by selecting the shortcut on my desktop (from the properties tab), but when I changed it to the actual atom.exe application it now works.

Answer (score 1):

In the properties tab of the file, where it says "opens with", I changed the path of Atom from the desktop shortcut to the direct path to the atom.exe application.